# Using different property name for jQueryUI autocomplete source data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jQueryUI autocomplete requires a source such as the following:

```
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

For my application, my webserver is getting the data from an API using cURL.  `label` and `value` should be the same, so I just need one of the two.  The server returns an `id` variable which I can access in the `select` callback and doesn't pose any problems.  Lastly, instead of using the property name "label" or "value", it uses the property name "name".  For instance, my data is:

```
[ { name: "Choice1", id: "1" }, ... ]
```

Question: Do I need to iterate over the API data prior to sending it to autocomplete, or can I configure autocomplete to use property name "name" instead of property name "label" or "value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a function for `source`:

> **Function**: The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:
>
> A `request` object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".
>
> A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

An example:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(req, resp){
    // Get your curl data
  }
});
```

If you edit your question and include some of your example code, I can improve my answer to you.